# Is it possible to use scikit TSNE on a large sparse matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix, dimensionality-reduction

The [scikit documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html) explains `fit_transform` can only be used for dense matrices, but I have a sparse matrix in csr format which I want to perform tsne on. The documentation says to use the `fit` method for sparse matrices, but this doesn't return the low dimensional embedding.

I appreciate I could use the `.todense()` method as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42541788/sklearn-tsne-with-sparse-matrix), but my data set is very large (0.4*10^6 rows and 0.5*10^4 columns) so wont fit in memory. Really, it would be nice to do this using sparse matrices. Is there a way to use scikit TSNE (or any other python implementation of TSNE) to reduce the dimensionality of a large sparse matrix and return the low dimensional embedding to then visualize?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that same documentation:

> It is highly recommended to use another dimensionality reduction method (e.g. PCA for dense data or TruncatedSVD for sparse data) to reduce the number of dimensions to a reasonable amount (e.g. 50) if the number of features is very high. This will suppress some noise and speed up the computation of pairwise distances between samples.

Use [`sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.TruncatedSVD.html) instead.

Comment: From my understanding of TSNE, it can be used on any degree of dimensionality, and given the structure of my data, I feel TSNE would work better than most other dimensionality reduction algorithms. I suppose this is a limitation of scikit though. Thanks for link!

Comment: @killerT2333 Have you seen UMAP (https://github.com/lmcinnes/umap)? Here, https://github.com/mmortazavi/UMAP_Nonlinear-Dimensionality-Reduction_Benchmark/blob/master/UMAP_Benchmark.ipynb, I compared UMAP with other methods including tSNE.